# Grouping an array by key and then summing totals

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to manipulate an array of data so it's grouped by a key, and then includes a property which shows the total for each group, and a total for all groups, however I'm running into trouble.

This is the data I'm starting with:

```
[ 
  {paren: 'abc', details: '', value: 100},
  {paren: 'abc', details: '', value: 120},
  {paren: 'vav', details: '', value: 400},
  {paren: 'aol', details: '', value: 40},
  {paren: 'ckk', details: '', value: 400},
  {paren: 'vav', details: '', value: 20}
]
```

And this is what I'd like to end up with. The total being the sum of value for all objects within a group, and grandTotal being the sum of all group totals.

```
const groupings = {
  grandTotal: 1080,
  groupings: [
    {
      group: 'abc', 
      data: [      
        {paren: 'abc', details: '', value: 100},
        {paren: 'abc', details: '', value: 120},
      ],
      total: 220
    },

    {
      group: 'vav', 
      data: [      
        {paren: 'vav', details: '', value: 400},
        {paren: 'vav', details: '', value: 20}
      ],
      total: 420
    },

    {
      group: 'aol', 
      data: [      
        {paren: 'aol', details: '', value: 40},
      ],
      total: 40
    },

    {
      group: 'ckk', 
      data: [      
        {paren: 'ckk', details: '', value: 400},
      ],
      total: 400
    },
  ]
};
```

I've been attempting to do this with a combination of reduce/map, and I'm pretty close. The only thing I haven't been able to figure out is how to efficiently do the totals. This is my code:

```
const mapGroups = array.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[item.paren] = obj[item.paren] || [];
  obj[item.paren].push(item);
  return obj;
}, {});

return Object.keys(mapGroups).map((key) => {
  return {group: key, data: mapGroups[key]};
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an object with the whole structure you want to `reduce`. Then you can update the nested objects during the loop. This allows you to add to each of the running totals and the grand total.

Finally, at the end you can replace the `groupings` object with an array of its values.

```js
const array = [ 
  {paren: 'abc', details: '', value: 100},
  {paren: 'abc', details: '', value: 120},
  {paren: 'vav', details: '', value: 400},
  {paren: 'aol', details: '', value: 40},
  {paren: 'ckk', details: '', value: 400},
  {paren: 'vav', details: '', value: 20}
];

const mapGroups = array.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj.groupings[item.paren] = obj.groupings[item.paren] || {
    group: item.paren,
    data: [],
    total: 0
  };
  obj.groupings[item.paren].data.push(item);
  obj.groupings[item.paren].total += item.value;
  obj.grandTotal += item.value;
  return obj;
}, {grandTotal: 0, groupings: {}});

mapGroups.groupings = Object.values(mapGroups.groupings);
console.log(mapGroups);
```